# building a sitemap.xml in clojure?

Tags: clojure, sitemap

Does anyone know of a clojure library to build sitemap.xml files? If no such library exists, should I create it? After doing some googling and searching SO didn't turn anything useful up, but I'd better ask first before I build one.

Comment: You might want to ask on the Clojure mailing list if you haven't already. I would bet that a library for this doesn't already exist, though. If you do make one, announce it on the list!

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler, Your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to ask on the Clojure mailing list if you haven't already. I would bet that a library for this doesn't already exist, though. If you do make one, announce it on the list!

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://github.com/hashobject/sitemap, it's a relatively new library.